# Unknown syntax in google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get the address or location of a google maps marker. However when I view the source code of the website I get a weird javascript call. Is there any way to resolve this to a usable Long/Lat?

This is what I see.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        //Get spu from unit id's        
        var spuMap = new Array();
        // initialization for property page is done in seperate function
        if ($("#pdp-container").length == 0){
            ha.map.property.init({location: [{a:'%32%30%2E

%35%34%35%35%32%35%39%35%34%32%31%34%37%30%37', b:'%2D%31%30%35%2E

%32%37%39%34%30%37%35%30%31%32%32%30%37', cLat:'%32%30%2E

%35%34%35%35%32%35%39%35%34%32%31%34%37%30%37', cLong:'%2D%31%30%35%2E

%32%37%39%34%30%37%35%30%31%32%32%30%37', id:'268534', exact:true, zoom:16, maxZoom:20, type:'u'}], 

mType: 'property'}, spuMap);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: what's the original source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some strange reason these parameters are URI encoded so simply call decodeURI on cLat and cLong, eg.

```
decodeURI(cLat);
```

And when you use it make sure to convert it to a number as google api takes coordinates as numbers.